# How do I undo blocks by anti-gamergate apps?

Tags: twitter

How do I unblock blocks made by anti-gamergate apps?

I noticed that my twitter account had blocked Brian Cox because he was on a blacklist of an anti-gamergate app.

Checking my Twitter Settings for Apps, I've got installed as apps Blocktogether and The Atheismplus.com Block Bot, though it's possible I have other anti-gamergate apps as well.

https://blocktogether.org/my-blocks is saying that I'm blocking 12149 users on Twitter, which is far too many to unblock manually. https://blocktogether.org/subscriptions indicates that I do not subscribe to any shared block lists, and I currently do not have any subscribers.

I couldn't find any info about opting out of blocktogether.

I'm worried that if I just revoke access to anti-gamergate apps, it'll just keep my current blocks as is, whereas I want to automatically undo any blocks done by anti-gamergate apps.

Comment: It's not possible to do so automatically, unless that app comes with an undo function